# "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException" SSL exception in server startup

Tags: java, security, ssl

I am getting an error trying to startup a server which has implemented SSL (TLS 3.0)

```
2016-04-04_17:34:26.139 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO g.a.c.c.g.d.ConnectorsController - Inside controller connectors processing request testConnectorConnection
2016-04-04_17:34:26.172 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  c.g.c.c.o.Office365ConnectorFactory -  testConnection() with connectProperties {clientId=fc5f7ca0-d91d-4af4-a735-bca01588abb5, tenantId=3beab17e-83ec-4b44-8f8b-632eaebd7a80, CSRFkey=4095a5f48a0445c1ec105d628bf332e91c805da7, action=testConnectorConnection, filePassword=qHuy+GjTE62UBV2D71aePA==, controller=connectors, datasourceName=Office365Connector2, office365KeyFilePath=/opt/gra/GuruO365MgmtApiPvtKeyIncl.pfx, connector_name=Office365, _=1459816491532, importtype=USER}
2016-04-04_17:34:26.434 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.m.a.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority - [Correlation ID: 33cffb7a-c2ef-4cfc-b2e5-ee6d455b2107] Instance discovery was successful
2016-04-04_17:34:27.075 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.m.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: 33cffb7a-c2ef-4cfc-b2e5-ee6d455b2107] Request to acquire token failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1874) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1857) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1378) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:140) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:80) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174) [adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163) [adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_99]
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:146) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:704) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:78) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:717) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: null
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:126) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
2016-04-04_17:34:27.076 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.g.c.c.o.Office365BaseConnector - Error in getAccessToken : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
2016-04-04_17:34:27.076 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.g.c.c.o.Office365ConnectorFactory - Exception while testConnection() execution ::  Not able to connect with Office365 with given credentials {SOURCE_FILE=user1459805666203.csv, clientId=fc5f7ca0-d91d-4af4-a735-bca01588abb5, tenantId=3beab17e-83ec-4b44-8f8b-632eaebd7a80, SCHEMA_FILE=user1459805666203.scm, CSRFkey=4095a5f48a0445c1ec105d628bf332e91c805da7, action=testConnectorConnection, filePassword=qHuy+GjTE62UBV2D71aePA==, controller=connectors, datasourceName=Office365Connector2, office365KeyFilePath=/opt/gra/GuruO365MgmtApiPvtKeyIncl.pfx, DELIMETER=,, connector_name=Office365, _=1459816491532, importtype=USER}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1874) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1857) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1378) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:140) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:80) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66) ~[adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174) [adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163) [adal4j-1.1.2.jar!/:1.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_99]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_99]
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:146) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:704) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:78) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:717) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: null
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:126) ~[sunec.jar:1.7.0_99]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
2016-04-04_17:34:27.076 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.g.c.c.o.Office365BaseConnector - Error in getAccessToken : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
```

Comment: There is no TLS 3.0, only SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1... . Apart from that the problem lies somewhere in your code or setup and both are not provided. With these information missing the question can not be answered fully but it looks like that the problems is related to improper setup of ECC cryptography.